# How to stop depth-first search when the target vertex of the graph is found?

Tags: python, graph, depth-first-search

Here is the graph:

```
g = {
    0: [2, 5, 7],
    1: [7],
    2: [0, 6],
    3: [5, 4],
    4: [3, 6, 7],
    5: [3, 4, 0],
    6: [2, 4],
    7: [0, 1, 4]
}
```

[image]

I have the following function in Python:

```
def dfs(graph, start, target, visited=None):
    if visited is None:
        visited = set()
    visited.add(start)

    for n in (set( graph[start] ) - visited):
        dfs(graph, n, target, visited)
    return visited
```

But it returns all the vertices that exists in the graph, and I want that it returns just the target vertex if it's present in the graph.
Could someone help me?

Comment: You aren't even checking if the target is found...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to test if you reached your target and, if you did, `return True`. This can be accomplished by making the following edits to your code:

Small edit for efficiency

```
def dfs(graph, start, target, visited=None):
    if visited is None:
        visited = set()
    visited.add(start)

    for n in (set( graph[start] ) - visited):
        if n == target:
            return True
        return dfs(graph, n, target, visited)
    return False
```

Edit: I made a mistake in my algorithm, fixed version is below:

```
def dfs(graph, start, target, visited=None):
    if start == target:
        return True
    if visited is None:
        visited = set()
    visited.add(start)

    found = False
    for n in (set( graph[start] ) - visited):
        if target == n:
            return True
        found = dfs(graph, n, target, visited)
    return found
```

Comment: It only returns False.

Comment: It returns `True` if found and `False` if it is not.

Comment: Not all vertices, I will edit the question and include the graph I'm using.

Comment: The code does not return True when I search for vertex 7 or 1, returns false, but for the other vertices it returns True!

Comment: There's nothing to apologize, helped me a lot!